# plantuml reporterror UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: plantuml

I have installed openjdk-18 on ubuntu23.04, then download plantuml and run below command:

```
java -jar plantuml.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2398)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:785)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1979)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:395)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:234)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:322)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:289)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2403)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:848)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2015)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.ColorModel$1.run(ColorModel.java:210)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.ColorModel$1.run(ColorModel.java:208)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.ColorModel.loadLibraries(ColorModel.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.ColorModel.<clinit>(ColorModel.java:220)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<clinit>(BufferedImage.java:286)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.FileFormat.<clinit>(FileFormat.java:134)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.Option.<init>(Option.java:113)
    at net.sourceforge.plantuml.Run.main(Run.java:95)
```